# In Python (2.7.3) how do I write a function that answers if any characters in str(x) are in str(y) (or str(y) are in str(x))?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, user-defined-functions

```
def char_check(x,y):

    if (str(x) in y or x.find(y) > -1) or (str(y) in x or y.find(x) > -1):

        return True

    else:

        return False

print "You will enter two words that you think use some of the same letters."

x = raw_input('Enter one of the words: ')

y = raw_input('Enter the other word: ')

print char_check(x,y)
```

What I am trying to do is enter two strings, such as "terrible" for str(x) and "bile" for str(y) and return "True" because the characters 'b', 'i', 'l', and 'e' are shared by both strings.

I'm new and trying to learn but I couldn't seem to figure this one out on my own. Thanks y'all.

Comment: Do you want any of the characters or all of the characters?  e.g. what should be the output for `terrible` and `boo`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. for 'terrible' and 'boo' the function should return True because of the 'b'

Comment: Is this an exercise in some tutorial or so? Even without sets, you should be able to write a quick solution using a for loop and `in`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich : yes this is from an exercise. The course I'm auditing hasn't introduced sets yet. How would I only use a for loop and "in" to do this?

Comment: loop over all the characters in one of the strings. If the character is in the other string, hurray, return True. If we finish and haven't returned yet, return False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
def char_check(x,y):
    if set(x) & set(y):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: It is worth avoiding an `if`-statement when the two branches just return `True` or `False` - just `return not (setx - sety) or not (sety - setx)`. Also, both of those conditions can be spelled more clearly using subset notation: `return setx <= sety or sety <= setx`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran this block, but it prints True if I enter 'shout' for x, 'true' for y. But they share the character 't'.

Comment: Sorry I got the requirement wrong. I thought they have to be complete subset of each other. Corrected now!

Comment: @Aro Thanks! the code a few answers back uses sets, and that accomplishes my goal. But, my textbook hasn't introduced sets yet. (It also hasn't introduced the ampersand (&) but your answer and the one above using sets accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 4):

Sets are almost certainly the way to go.

```
>>> set1 = set("terrible")
>>> set2 = set("bile")
>>> set1.issubset(set2)
False
>>> set2.issubset(set1)  # "bile" is a subset of "terrible"
True
>>> bool(set1 & set2)  # at least 1 character in set1 is also in set2
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked through Python documentation for a few hours trying to see what syntax I could change but the 'set' accomplishes what I wanted!